# Augmented reality for physical building models not working well with vuforia

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia, metaio

We have team working on AR APP which is being developed using vuforia SDK. Develops need to show information based on various building models which are part of same large model.

AR app should scan various parts of models which can be individual building, restaurant, garden parking space or any other physical object in the model.

So far developers are able to scan various parts of models but app fails to scan models properly from differ angles and distances

Not sure if vuforia was the right choice for this kind of project. Metaio Would have been good choice with its capability of scanning 3D models well as compared to vuforia.

Now my question is vuforia right choice for physical 3D models or Metaio is the right choice

How can we further improve object recognition from different angles in vuforia

Object of app

To detect physical object and show related information like image, video, map, floor plans.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before with Vuforia but as I were targeting large objects my approach was to take multiple images of the buildings from different angles with professional camera and make sure that the image rating was above 3 stars and it worked for me I honestly did not use Metaio before but this what i have done with Vuforia